# Inner Join Excel recordset with Access recordset

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access, vb6

Is it possible to make an inner join between an excel spreadsheet and and access database table?
I tried many ways to make this possible but with no success.

This is my Visual Basic 6 code:

```
Dim DbTemp As Database
Dim ExcelDB As Database
DIm xlsRs As Recordset

Set DbTemp = OpenDatabase(App.Path + "\mydb.mdb")
Set ExcelDB = OpenDatabase(App.path + "\QueryExcelDATA.xls", False, True, "Excel 8.0;")
Set xlsRS = ExcelDB.OpenRecordset(query, dbOpenDynaset) ' query is a sql query I used to get some other results

Do Until xlsRs.EOF
        Workspaces(0).BeginTrans
            sql =  "INSERT INTO Presenze(Enterprise, Emp_ID, mYear, mMonth, mDay, WorkHours) " _
                 & " SELECT Presenze.Emp_ID, '"+xlsRs("Entps")+"', '" + xlsRs("Yr") + "', '" + " _
                 & " xlsRs("Mnth") + "', '" + xlsRs("Dy") + "', '" + xlsRs("WH") + `"' " _
                & " FROM [ExcelDATA$] INNER JOIN Presenze On [ExcelDATA$].[CardID] = Presenze.CardID"
            DbTemp.Execute sql
        Workspaces(0).CommitTrans
        xlsRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

I want to get the data from [ExcelData$] spreadsheet and insert them to access Table "Presenze"
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The only realistic way to do this is to create an import table in your access DB and copy the data from Excel into it then join to this table.  That way you don't have to recreate the join everytime the data in Excel changes.